# Batch geocoding software that works in Japan

Tags: geocoding

I have 185,000 pairs of Japanese zip codes and I wish to calculate the driving distance between each pair

I am able to do this individually for each pair using tools such as:

http://www.mapdevelopers.com/distance_from_to.php

But I need to do all or most of them at the same time. I have already contacted Maptive and they say they can't do what I'm after, even if I pay

Any help anyone can give me would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Which OS would be acceptable (or must it be a web-app)? Any price limit?

Comment: "all or most of them at the same time": What do you mean? C(185000,2) means an astronomic number of combinations if you want to run them all at the same time.

Comment: Sorry I should have cleared those things up. I need the software to be windows compatible or web-based, priced under $1,000

Comment: I don't need to do them all simultaneously but in some reasonable batches. I suppose even 1,000 pairs at a time would be workable although this issue is time-sensitive. I need to be able to do the whole database (excel format) in a day or 2 days.                                     Thanks for your questions guys!